# Ubuntu 22.04.02 - Strange rainbow during startup

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, 22.04, startup

When loading ubuntu (before login screen) for approx. 1 second a strange rainbow appears on the bottom of the screen. At first glance I though it might be some kind of memory error but I still have old 18.04 ubuntu version with 15.10 kernel and it's not visible there. I have all uptades installed. Do yoy think it's more ubuntu problem or might it be related with hardware? Passmark Memtest didn't detect anything.

Here the photo (sorry for not too bad quality, in reality colors are going more in red and yellow than the ones visible here, the line is just few pixels as it takes 1-2 percent of image height):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qsrnyOFDYZOoPwJ7XXIyZ2R60twkZfG5/view?usp=sharing

I have amd 5700g with no external graphics card. Only APU. That might have some importance here.

Any ideas?